# Permission denied on importing using psql

Tags: database, postgresql, import, permissions, psql

I am trying to import a sql file . Problem I am getting is permission denied. I saw some solutions online but none have worked for me so far. I have already tried giving everyone permissions to the file. Also is it weird that I am unable to run the regular psql command in my command promt. Is that weird or no? If you have any other solutions please let me know. I am running on a windows 10.

```
test=# \i C:\Users\Adrian\Downloads\personn.sql
C:: Permission denied
```

Comment: What happens if you do: `\i 'C:\Users\Adrian\Downloads\personn.sql'`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yes, I also tried this and it says no such file or directory.
```C:UsersAdrianDownloadspersonn.sql: No such file or directory```

Comment: When you where changing permissions did you do that for the directories above the file also?

Comment: I did it for the downloads folder and the users folder named "Adrian" and entire C: drive and still doesn't work @AdrianKlaver

Comment: The only idea I have left is reverse the slashes: `C:/Users/Adrian/Downloads/personn.sql`.

Comment: hmm that worked but when i tried that before I got an error. I mustve had a typo when I did that the first time . Thank you for suggesting that.